# Regex using Vala and GLib

Tags: regex, linux, glib, vala

Is there a function, something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php ?

Using GLib http://references.valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.MatchInfo, all i'v found is :

```
public bool match_all_full (string str, ssize_t string_len = -1, int start_position = 0,  RegexMatchFlags match_options = 0, out MatchInfo match_info = null) throws RegexError
Using the standard algorithm for regular expression matching only the longest match in the string is retrieved, it is not possible to obtain all the available matches.
```

and it says **it is not possible to obtain all the available matches.**

I wasn't able to find any working code sample. Thanks for your help.

**Note:**

the objective is to parse a plist file (i only need CFBundleIdentifier and CFBundleName values)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>nodejs</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Node.js</string>
    <key>DocSetPlatformFamily</key>
    <string>nodejs</string>
    <key>isDashDocset</key><true/><key>dashIndexFilePath</key><string>nodejs    /api/documentation.html</string></dict>
</plist>
```

I have these dependencies availabes (the ubuntu synapse package):

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9),
dh-autoreconf,
gnome-common,
valac (>= 0.16.0),
libzeitgeist-2.0-dev (>= 0.9.14),
libdbus-glib-1-dev,
libgtk-3-dev (>= 3.0.0),
libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.28.0),
libgee-0.8-dev (>= 0.5.2),
libjson-glib-dev (>= 0.10.0),
libkeybinder-3.0-dev,
libnotify-dev,
librest-dev,
libappindicator3-dev (>= 0.0.7)
```

As a results it gives me

```
** Message: main.vala:28: CFBundleIdentifier: cakephp
** Message: main.vala:28: CFBundleName: CakePHP
** Message: main.vala:28: DocSetPlatformFamily: cakephp
```

To the question why not using  xmllib ?
    The project has few dependecies, in a GNU system (despite i'm a newbie), programs are packaged assuming only certains dependency, if i wan"t my plugin to be used, i think i have to use only the available dependencies or i might broke something et block the update for the endsudoer.

Comment: Why not use the XML library?

Comment: This should be done using a XML library, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets take a look at some of the context around that quote you cited, with emphasis added:

> **Using the standard algorithm** for regular expression matching only the longest match in the string is retrieved, **it is not possible to obtain all the available matches**. For instance matching "`<a> <b> <c>`" against the pattern "`<.*>`" you get "`<a> <b> <c>`".
>
> **This function uses a different algorithm** (called DFA, i.e. deterministic finite automaton), so it can retrieve all the possible matches, all starting at the same point in the string. For instance matching "`<a> <b> <c>`" against the pattern "`<.*>;`" you would obtain three matches: "`<a> <b> <c>`", "`<a> <b>`" and "`<a>`".

That said, that isn't the "all" you are looking for—your case is much simpler.  All you need to do is iterate through the matches from the standard algorithm:

```
private static int main (string[] args) {
    string contents;
    GLib.Regex exp = /\<key\>([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\<\/key\>[\n\t ]*\<string\>([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)\<\/string\>/;

    assert (args.length > 1);
    try {
        GLib.FileUtils.get_contents (args[1], out contents, null);
    } catch (GLib.Error e) {
        GLib.error ("Unable to read file: %s", e.message);
    }

    try {
        GLib.MatchInfo mi;
        for (exp.match (contents, 0, out mi) ; mi.matches () ; mi.next ()) {
            GLib.message ("%s: %s", mi.fetch (1), mi.fetch (2));
        }
    } catch (GLib.Error e) {
        GLib.error ("Regex failed: %s", e.message);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be fine, but this may not work at all, because it's not guaranteed that the <string> and <key> node are on the same line.